# converting integer to string to show in glutbitmap

Tags: c, opengl

I'm trying to convert my score from integer to string. The glutbitmap doesnt recognize string. How to make it recognize.So far I've done this

```
    while(z>9)
        {
            k = z % 10;            
            glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,48+k); 

        //   glRasterPos2f ((posx-(j*space_char)),posy,);    

           z = z/10;
          //  glRasterPos3f ((posx-(j*space_char)), posy, posz);    
       }

    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,48+z);  


    glFlush();
}
```

The above code is showing integer but after 9 it shows 01,11,21,31,41 it is coming opposite. So please help me in resolving this in OPENGL.

Comment: Sir u didn't get my question. I need to do it in glutBitmap not printf

Comment: char buf[10];
            snprintf(buf, 10, "%d", score);
            glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,buf);

Comment: this is what i've done and not working

Comment: Once you get a string from `sprintf()` [loop over it and call `glutBitmapCharacter()` for each character](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14319/44729).